# Avoiding maximum recursion depth in connected component analysis?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to label all elements of a connected component. The links of the graph is formatted with a dictionary of dictionaries. The algorithm with recursion seems to be fast, unfortunatelly for larger graphs the maximum recursion depth is making problems and I do not want to increase the maximum recursion length every time. Do you know how to rewrite this code so the depth does not trouble anymore?

```
import numpy as np
def find_components(dists):

    N = len(dists.keys())
    labels = np.zeros(N, dtype = np.int) - 1
    n = 0
    steps = 0 

    def walk(j):
        for k in dists[j].keys():
            if (labels[k] == -1):
                labels[k] = labels[j]
                walk(k)

    remains = (labels == -1)
    while n < N:
        i = np.arange(0,N,1)[remains][np.random.randint(0,N - n)]
        labels[i] = i
        walk(i)
        remains = (labels == -1)
        n = N - len(np.nonzero(remains)[0])
    unique = np.unique(labels)
    labels_ = np.zeros(N, dtype = np.int) - 1
    for i, label in enumerate(unique):
        labels_[labels == label] = i
    return labels_
```

Comment: Seems you're using a DFS (depth-first search) here, which might go very deep on specific input data. I think you may rewrite it in a BFS (breadth-first search) manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `walk()` from a recursive function to an iterative version:

```
import collections

def walk(j):
    lifo = collections.deque(j)

    while lifo:
        for k in dists[lifo.pop()].keys():
            if labels[k] == -1:
               labels[k] = labels[j]
               lifo.append(k)
```

Comment: Which is also BFS. Thank you!